# How to find UNIX time of compilation

Tags: c++, datetime, visual-c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to be able to get the UNIX time (seconds since the epoch) at which a C++ program was compiled.

How should I do this with preprocessor declarations?

I figure that once I have the UNIX time of compilation calculated, everything else can be based off of that.

Comment: Are `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` sufficient?  (These don't produce a UNIX timestamp, but you may be able to convert them to one at runtime...)

Comment: `__TIME__` doesn't give me a number.  `__TIME__` is a string, and the preprocessor doesn't play nicely with strings.

Comment: I realise that.  But you can convert them to a timestamp at runtime.

Comment: Also, you've marked this as "Visual C++", which implies Windows, which implies that a Unix timestamp is not going to be a native concept...

Comment: I would rather do it in the preprocessor than at runtime.

Comment: as to why a unix timestamp: is there any better integer timestamp?

Comment: @StackTracer: I don't think you're going to find a pure preprocessor solution.  Either do the conversion at runtime, or pass in a `#define` on the command-line.

Comment: Oli, okay.  I had a hope that there was a way to do it with preprocessing, but seeing how limited the language is in that respect, I'll try to find something else.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you are right it doesn't I'll remove the comment.

Comment: Compile time is a slightly fuzzy concept when you bring in things like link-time code generation.  How about pulling the TimeDateStamp field from the executable's (or DLL's) PE header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill an `tm` struct with the compile time using `sscanf` and `__DATE__` and/or `__TIME__`.
Convert the object to unix time using `mktime` that gives you an `time_t`.

```
tm compile_time;

...

sscanf(__DATE__, "%s %d %d", month, &compile_time.tm_mday, &compile_time.tm_year);

...

time_t timestamp = mktime(&compile_time);
```

Note that you have to convert the monthname to an integer (0-11).

Answer (score -1):

C++ provides a number of predefined macros including  `__TIME__`

Macro   Description

```
__LINE__    This contain the current line number of the program when it is being compiled.

__FILE__    This contain the current file name of the program when it is being compiled.

__DATE__    This contains a string of the form month/day/year that is the date of the translation of the source file into object code.

__TIME__    This contains a string of the form hour:minute:second that is the time at which the program was compiled.
```

Let us see an example for all the above macros:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "Value of __LINE__ : " << __LINE__ << endl;
    cout << "Value of __FILE__ : " << __FILE__ << endl;
    cout << "Value of __DATE__ : " << __DATE__ << endl;
    cout << "Value of __TIME__ : " << __TIME__ << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If we compile and run above code, this would produce the following result:

```
Value of __LINE__ : 6
Value of __FILE__ : test.cpp
Value of __DATE__ : Mai 17 2014
Value of __TIME__ : 18:52:48
```

Comment: You have not answered the question, just posted a bunch of useless info that I already stated I was not looking for.

Comment: First  Calm down , second  You cannot do what you want because this is the only way to get time compilation and you can see C++ standards

Comment: okay, sorry if the wording was a little strong.  I guess I will just have to find a non-c++ solution to the problem.